# Yii2: Is it possible to apply an RBAC rule to a guest?

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

Is it possible to apply an RBAC [yii\rbac\Rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-rule.html) to a non-authenticated user (`Yii::$app->user->isGuest == true`)? If so, how?

The rule I have is also used for authenticated users and it would be nice and DRY to keep all the logic in one place, like this:

```php
class UserAccesslevelRule extends Rule {
    public $name = 'userAccesslevel';

    public function execute($userID, $item, $params) {
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest && $someotherlogic == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if ($somelogic == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where u want to apply rules for guest user, In controller ?

Comment: How would you prepare the system to distinguish between guests?

Comment: @Mohan In controller or in some logic in a model.

Comment: @Bizley Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Since there is no difference between guests (without additional implementation) every guest would get the same permissions and so there is no point of preparing RBAC rules for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACF  ( Access Control Filter) where  in the controller you can assign the action allowed for guest

from Yii2 guide

> ```
>   use yii\web\Controller;
>   use yii\filters\AccessControl;
>
>   class SiteController extends Controller
>   {
>       public function behaviors()
>       {
>           return [
>               'access' => [
>                   'class' => AccessControl::className(),
>                   'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'],
>                   'rules' => [
>                       [
>                           'allow' => true,
>                           'actions' => ['login', 'signup'],
>                           'roles' => ['?'],  // <----- guest 
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           'allow' => true,
>                           'actions' => ['logout'],
>                           'roles' => ['@'],
>                       ],
>                   ],
>               ],
>           ];
>       }
>       // ...
>   }
> ```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

with the RBAC you can define  also new rules   see this for a new rules http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#using-rules     but seems that you want redefine  the behavior for is guest .. the isGuest attribute and getIsGuest() public methoed are defined  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html  could be that  for this you should extend  this class  and  redefine  the isGuest function ..

Comment: I need to add some logic to the rule, so this won't do it. By rule in my question I meant a app\rbac\Rule class that I have created. There are other SO answers about the method you describe here.

Comment: I have update the answer with some suggestio about your comment hope this is useful ..

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, you can do like

```
    use yii\filters\AccessControl;

    class controllerName extends Controller {

    public function behaviors() {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['index','Other_action_names'],
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'actions' => ['index','Other_action_names'],
                            'roles' => (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) ? ["@"] : [],   // Your roles
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

   public function actionIndex() {


            $searchModel = new SearchModel();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('index', [
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);

    }

    }
```

Hope this will work for you.